# Added GNOME PPAs but not receiving the update?

Tags: gnome, updates, repository

I've added them both via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` and updated the repositories and then after ran a dist-upgrade but received no updates at all. I'm trying to do this because of the newer version's performance improvements.
I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1LTS

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have added these PPAs blindly.
Visit their pages and select Bionic from drop down and you will get:

1. [`ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3-staging?field.series_filter=bionic)

   > **Package**                         **Version**                              **Uploaded by**
   >   `fonts-cantarell`     0.101-1~ubuntu18.04.1       Jeremy Bicha (2018-03-15)
2. [`ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/ubuntu/gnome3?field.series_filter=bionic)

   > **Package**                         **Version**                                                                                                       **Uploaded by**
   >    `gnome-photos`    3.27.92-1~ubuntu18.04.1 (Newer version available)     Jeremy Bicha (2018-03-17)

   *Newer version available* link above [points to unstable version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-photos/3.28.0-1) not for Bionic.

So there are no new packages for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in these PPAs.